# out of memory double update sqlite android

Tags: android, sqlite, memory

Well im a beginner and this is my first android app, and i get this problem

```
Failure 21 "Out of memory" on 0x0 when preparing 'update clients set lat=19.124566,lng=-103.23546 where id=1'
```

In my table structure i set lat and lng as DOUBLE.

I read about it and some people say the SD card needs to be bigger, but then I set the SD card of the emulator to 5Gb, I'm using android 1.6 hope you can help me. thanks =D

soome code here.

```
    try {
        dir1 = new Geocoder(this).getFromLocationName(dir_1, 1);
         Address address = dir1.get(0);
            if(address.hasLatitude() && address.hasLongitude()){
                double selectedLat = address.getLatitude();
                double selectedLng = address.getLongitude();
                adapter.command("UPDATE clientes set lat_1="+selectedLat*1000000+",lng_1="+selectedLng*1000000+" WHERE id="+idCliente);                                              
                Log.e("geo","location1: "+selectedLat+" : "+selectedLng);
            }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        Log.e("error","Error en la direccion 1");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears that this error message is misleading and might have nothing to do with storage space or memory.  This [post](http://mobilephonedevelopment.com/android-developer-tips/#Failure%2021%20%28out%20of%20memory%29%20on%200%C3%970%20when%20preparing) suggests it occurs when you have an error in your SQL.

Without seeing some of your code, it is hard to give more specific suggestions.  Can you post some?

Comment: i have tried the query using a sqlite client and it runs well! ill post something!

Comment: What is the class type of your adapter object?  Why are you not using SQLiteDatabase.update()?  See: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html

Answer (score 0):

So im guessing your command method just puts that string into an execSql() method.
You will need to append the semi-colon within the string to execute, so:

```
adapter.command("UPDATE clientes set lat_1="+selectedLat*1000000+",lng_1="+selectedLng*1000000+" WHERE id="+idCliente+";");
```